# Android Spinner not selecting item - specific devices

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm facing a problem with a Spinner in certain android devices: I click on an item but the spinner position doesn't change.

I've seen this problem on a Galaxy S2 (4.0.3 API 15) and an Avvio Chinese device (4.0.4 API 15). The Log behaviour for each of them is somehow different, as follows:

Avvio:

```
I/InputDispatcher(234): channel '41c8acc8 PopupWindow:418f39c8 (server)' ~ abortBrokenDispatchCycle - notify=false
```

Galaxy S2:

```
I/InputDispatcher(1995): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel 'xxxx'
```

Here's my `xml` configuration:

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/status_spinner"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="0dip"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
```

And the (stripped) code:

```
Spinner status_spinner;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    status_spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.status_spinner);
    status_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Selected status code " + position);
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter){
            Log.d(TAG, "Nothing selected");
        }
    });
}
```

After those messages nothing happens, no event is fired. I'm getting the first spinner event though, the one that fires when the spinner is initialized and selects the first item, but nothing more after that.

This does work in other devices, from API level 8 to the newest devices. I'm really stuck with this, any clues?

**Solved:** The Spinner was contained in a `LinearLayout` that had `android:animateLayoutChanges` set to `true`. Changing it to `false` solved the issue.

Comment: Please provide some code snippet so that we can help you better.

Comment: Are you sure you implement the correct interface? The [OnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) requires the onNothingSelected() method to be implemented as well. You can try to implement this method and Log a message as well. It might be the case that the spinner is dismissed for some reason.

Comment: I do have the onNothingSelected() method, I just didn't include it, edited now.

Comment: Please post your solution from the edit as an answer, it's quite interesting.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi I can't reproduce the problem with a few lines of code, it might be the combination with other views in my layout. I realised I had a similar problem with a ListView that included an animated hiding/showing of an object.